# Free software to create a map server that can be installed directly in a subdomain without a server install?

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations

I want to create a web map page using my own shapefiles but all the map server software that I’ve seen need to be installed directly in the server.

Is there any software that allows me to create a map server just by putting the files in some folder and "execute" them (like php or js, for example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [Openlayers](https://openlayers.org/) after converting your shapefiles to GML, JSON, or KML. [Ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) is useful for the conversion step; see [OGR vector formats](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html) for format details. [(source)](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/How-to-display-shapefile-tp2633343p2633343.html)